# Using Azure DevOps Server 2022 (On-Premise) with Visual Studio Code for Java Project

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, tfs, ide

We are using Azure DevOps Server 2022 (On-Premise) for Source Control, integrated with Visual Studio 2022 for all .NET Projects.

We have recently inherited a Java project, and have decided to use Visual Studio Code IDE for development.

We want to continue to use Azure DevOps Server 2022 for Source Control for this Java project through Visual Studio Code. It appears however that the official extension for Azure DevOps has been deprecated:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/blob/master/DEPRECATED.md

What would be the best way to achieve Source Control with Azure DevOps 2022 with Visual Studio Code for a Java Project?

Is there a better Java IDE to use for this other than Visual Studio Code, that allows a more integrated experience like Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC for version control?

Comment: I am using TFVC for my source control

Comment: Maybe you can check the extension [discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/issues/643).  In addition,  i notice there's a VS code extension `Argutec Azure Repos`, it can be installed and actually points to the same extension above. However i'm failed to `team signin`

Comment: Thank you Wade, I will check this and get back to you. In case this extension doesnt work, do you have any suggestions for other TFS extensions for VS Code? Or another IDE entirely?

Comment: I don't find other VS code extension to manage the TFVC, or IDE.  As suggested in the [link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/blob/master/DEPRECATED.md#why-are-we-doing-this), Developers still using TFVC with VS Code will need to use an external version control client such as the tf command line.